# An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details in Windows 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have just started using Android studio every time i try to install an avd i get an error message "An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details." i am using windows 10 And in log file i get this.

```
2019-12-17 13:32:13,479 [ thread 35]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create the SD card. 
2019-12-17 13:32:13,480 [ thread 35]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder. 
2019-12-17 13:32:16,987 [Alarm Pool]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 55 ms
```

Can Anybody help? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try to uninstall Android emulator and re-install again. It worked for me.
[image: Re-install Android emulator]

Comment: How to open SDK manager in Android Studio: Click on the "File" menu in the top left corner. Click on "Settings" in the dropdown menu. In the left sidebar, click on "Appearance & Behavior". Click on "System Settings" and then click on "Android SDK". This will open the Android SDK Manager, where you can manage your installed SDK components, including the Android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I was try to reinstall Android SDK, and after start application sdk was opennig last project.

Close the project and Android SDK will start setup wizard wich will download all necessary files and install Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the same message with the sd card.

Firstly, I had to (or not, I don't know exactly what fixed the problem) rename my windows username because I had a whitespace char in it (there shouldn't be whitespaces in the route to the Android sdk (C:\Users"yourWindowsUsernameWithoutWhitespace"....), even AS warns you). It's not that simple to change it but here's the solution:

https://support.microsoft.com/hu-hu/help/2454362/renaming-a-user-account-does-not-automatically-change-the-profile-path

(In AS I tried to redownload and reinstall the android sdk to a different folder without space in it's route but for some reason the installation never finished)

After this, the problem still existed. I closed Android Studio and ran it as administrator. And worked! I hope I helped

Answer (score -5):

Follow below steps to install AVD in android studio

1. Select ‘Clone Device’ option , selecting this will add new device into list with appending ‘(edited)1’ string.
2. Select this clone device: press ‘Next’
3. Select this clone device: press ‘Next’
4. Select system image as per your requirement: press ‘Next’
5. Select ‘Show Advance Setting’ scroll down: in ‘Memory and Storage’ choose ‘External file’ (which is disable/gray-out in actual device but available in clone device) keep entry empty.
6. Press ‘Finish